# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1h_n(x)\,d\mu_n(x)$, where $\int_0^1d\mu_n(x)=1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=h(x)$, and $\mu_n\to\mu^*$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I would like to compute the following limit

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_0^1h_n(x)\,d\mu_n(x),$$ and I know that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1d\mu_n(x)&=1, \forall n,\\
\lim_{n\to +\infty}h_n(x)&=h(x),\end{align*}
and 
$$\mu_n\to\mu^*$$
in the weak sense of the test functions.

Can I conclude something about the first limit? Do I need some particular conditions?

Comment: Your three main go-to theorems for moving limits inside integrals are Fatou's Lemma, the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. Do you have any of those theorem conditions satisfied?

Comment: Do you have any more information on $h_n,\,\mu_n,$ or $h?$

Comment: In what sense is $\mu_n\to\mu^*?$

Comment: In the weak sense of the test functions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I'm not your man, but I feel like the question is clarified sufficiently, now.